# How to run GTK application on text mode of ubuntu and rotate to portrait view without x-server?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, xserver, xvfb, xinit

I am using ubuntu on text only with terminal in portrait mode to run the GTK application. I have removed GUI/Desktop mode. I tried to run it on ubuntu and other Linux operating systems.

I used 'startx' and 'xinit' without using x server.

The application is able to run, but it is running in landscape view only while I am using ubuntu in text mode with portrait view.

I tried the following commands,

```
$ xinit ./(gtk application)
```

I also tried to embed 'xinit' with 'xrandr -o left ' as below,

```
$ xinit && xrandr -o left ./(gtk application)
```

but above is also not making the application run in the portrait mode.

However when I tried the 'xinit' command alone, then a temporary **xserver** white window of **xinit** opens up in the landscape view, where I was able to run and rotate the application in portrait view using *'xrandr -o left'* command followed by application running as below mentioned,

**In the text mode console**

```
$ xinit
```

**In the 'xinit' white console**

```
$ xrandr -o left
$ ./(gtk_application)
```

But I want to make application run and rotate into portrait view using a single line command on text mode console only, with or without writing any script.

I tried to make a script with the above commands and run it, still I didn't get any results.

I used **xvfb** also to run the gtk application using `xvfb-run ./(gtk application)` command but nothing seems to be promising

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks